# Value cannot be null, parameter name: source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending collection of objects to my viewmodel like this

**Controller**

```
SoundsViewModel model = new SoundsViewModel(sound, AllGroups());
```

**ViewModel**

```
public SoundsViewModel(sound, List<LocationGroup> allGroups)
        {
            ....

            Groups = new List<SoundLocationGroupViewModel>();
            if (allGroups !=null)
            {
                foreach (var item in allGroups)
                {
                    var i = (from r in sound.LocationGroups where r.Id == item.Id select r).FirstOrDefault();
                    Groups.Add(new SoundLocationGroupViewModel() { LocationGroupId = item.Id, LocationGroupName = item.Name, IsInLocationGroup = (i != null) });
                } 
            }
        }
```

**Error message is**

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

 var i = (from r in sound.LocationGroups where r.Id == item.Id select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Obviously this message seems to be perfect and clear in describe situation but in debbuging I'm getting allGroups collection populated and properly received on the viewmodel.

Any ideas, it's late and would really appreciate if someone suggest me a hint how to fix this in tommorow morning cofee.

Thanks

Update:
Now it's passed.

```
foreach (var item in allGroups)
 {
    if(sound.LocationGroups !=null)
    {
     var i = (from r in sound.LocationGroups where r.Id == item.Id select r).FirstOrDefault();
     Groups.Add(new SoundLocationGroupViewModel() { LocationGroupId = item.Id, LocationGroupName = item.Name, IsInLocationGroup = (i != null) });
    }
```

}

Comment: Is `sound.LocationGroups` `null`?

Comment: I would try and do var groups = sound.LocationGroups and then do groups.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == item.Id);

Comment: @PaulMcCowat That would still produce the same error. A `null` check is in order; that, or initializing to an empty collection.

Comment: Thanks, I should have put that in. The point I was making was extending on yours, eliminate the possibility of nulls

Comment: What's with the first argument of the `UserViewModel` constructor? Looks pretty much invalid C# this `sound` stuff. Where does it come from and have you ensured that it is not null?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Changed that UserViewModel to SoundsViewModel, typo. Great eye though.

Comment: The typo's still there, can't you see it? `public SoundsViewModel(sound, ...`. Also you didn't answer my question about where does this variable come from and whether you have verified if it is not null.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`source` is likely coming from the FirstOrDefault() extension method:</strike>

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

For some reason your Linq query is returning null.  Try it in two steps (and use `Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault` since you're just checking for a non-null result):

```
bool isInGroup;
var q = (from r in sound.LocationGroups where r.Id == item.Id select r);
isInGroup = (q != null && q.Any());

Groups.Add(new SoundLocationGroupViewModel() 
    {
         LocationGroupId = item.Id, 
         LocationGroupName = item.Name, 
         IsInLocationGroup = isInGroup 
    });
```

For what it's worth `source` is still coming from a Linq extension method, just not the one I thought.  Since `sound.LocationGroups` is `null` the exception is coming from the extension method (I'd guess `Where`) that the linq statement gets compiled to.